# setOnClickListener crash

Tags: android, crash, clicklistener

I've read some questions about this on stackoverflow but it didn't solved my issue.

I'm following  a guide about toasting messages on a click command.. but it crashes (i wonder how if i'm just copying a guide)

the code is :

```
  @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ImageView red_view=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView3);

    red_view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
             Toast t=Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"ROSSO",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        t.show();
         }

         });
```

what am i missing? :/

Logcat This is the logcat (i dunno how to make it a quote :/ )

04-26 12:50:36.360: E/AndroidRuntime(928): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 04-26 12:50:36.360: E/AndroidRuntime(928): Process: com.example.firstapp, PID: 928 04-26 12:50:36.360: E/AndroidRuntime(928): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.firstapp/com.example.firstapp.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException 04-26 12:50:36.360: E/AndroidRuntime(928): at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195) 04-26 12:50:36.360: E/AndroidRuntime(928): at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245) 04-26 12:50:36.360: E/AndroidRuntime(928): at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 04-26 12:50:36.360: E/AndroidRuntime(928): at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 04-26 12:50:36.360: E/AndroidRuntime(928): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 04-26 12:50:36.360: E/AndroidRuntime(928): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 04-26 12:50:36.360: E/AndroidRuntime(928): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017) 04-26 12:50:36.360: E/AndroidRuntime(928): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 04-26 12:50:36.360: E/AndroidRuntime(928): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 04-26 12:50:36.360: E/AndroidRuntime(928): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779) 04-26 12:50:36.360: E/AndroidRuntime(928): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595) 04-26 12:50:36.360: E/AndroidRuntime(928): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 04-26 12:50:36.360: E/AndroidRuntime(928): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException 04-26 12:50:36.360: E/AndroidRuntime(928): at com.example.firstapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:25) 04-26 12:50:36.360: E/AndroidRuntime(928): at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231) 04-26 12:50:36.360: E/AndroidRuntime(928): at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087) 04-26 12:50:36.360: E/AndroidRuntime(928): at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159) 04-26 12:50:36.360: E/AndroidRuntime(928): ... 11 more 04-26 12:50:38.660: I/Process(928): Sending signal. PID: 928 SIG: 9 04-26 12:50:42.540: D/AndroidRuntime(980): Shutting down VM 04-26 12:50:42.540: W/dalvikvm(980): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb2a87ba8) 04-26 12:50:42.550: E/AndroidRuntime(980): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 04-26 12:50:42.550: E/AndroidRuntime(980): Process: com.example.firstapp, PID: 980 04-26 12:50:42.550: E/AndroidRuntime(980): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.firstapp/com.example.firstapp.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException 04-26 12:50:42.550: E/AndroidRuntime(980): at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195) 04-26 12:50:42.550: E/AndroidRuntime(980): at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245) 04-26 12:50:42.550: E/AndroidRuntime(980): at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 04-26 12:50:42.550: E/AndroidRuntime(980): at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 04-26 12:50:42.550: E/AndroidRuntime(980): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 04-26 12:50:42.550: E/AndroidRuntime(980): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 04-26 12:50:42.550: E/AndroidRuntime(980): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017) 04-26 12:50:42.550: E/AndroidRuntime(980): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 04-26 12:50:42.550: E/AndroidRuntime(980): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 04-26 12:50:42.550: E/AndroidRuntime(980): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779) 04-26 12:50:42.550: E/AndroidRuntime(980): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595) 04-26 12:50:42.550: E/AndroidRuntime(980): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 04-26 12:50:42.550: E/AndroidRuntime(980): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException 04-26 12:50:42.550: E/AndroidRuntime(980): at com.example.firstapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:25) 04-26 12:50:42.550: E/AndroidRuntime(980): at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231) 04-26 12:50:42.550: E/AndroidRuntime(980): at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087) 04-26 12:50:42.550: E/AndroidRuntime(980): at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159) 04-26 12:50:42.550: E/AndroidRuntime(980): ... 11 more 04-26 12:50:44.760: I/Process(980): Sending signal. PID: 980 SIG: 9

(I tried to make clickable the object and crashes anyway) and this is my layout file http://it.tinypic.com/r/t0j5u1/8

Comment: Likely activity_main does not have a view with id `imageView3`

Comment: post your layout file

Comment: Can you please post your logcat snippet and layout xml file ?

Comment: Do you have an ImageView with id imageView3 in activity_main?

Answer (score 2):

Your `imageView3` is in a fragment layout and not in the `activity_main` layout. Therefore it cannot be found in your activity `onCreate()`.

Move the code to the fragment `onCreateView()` and call `findViewById()` on the fragmen layout you just inflated, e.g.

```
View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_fragment_layout);
ImageView red_view=(ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
red_view.setOnClickListener(...);
return rootView;
```

Answer (score 0):

see this

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonToast);

        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

              @Override
              public void onClick(View arg0) {

                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                               "Button is clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

              }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If your setting a click event in ImageView then set the property

```
android:clickable="true"
```

in your layout xml file.